# Is possible create multiline as separate object?

Tags: ios, swift

Is possible to do in textView create multiline as separate object ? What i try to do is one textView, one fextField and one button. Now when i type in textField some text and press Button i would like add this text to line (for example line number 1)

> 1 My text

After this system want add other line for example some log to line number 2

> 1 My text
>
> 2 Computer text

And now i want type some text : hey my next text and after click button i want see this text like continue in my line number 1

> 1 my text hey my next text
>
> 2 Computer text

And the last if i click button for empty textField i would like start type in next line number 3

I don't have any idea how can i reach this goal ? Ca anyone give me some hint ?

Comment: I'd suggest you make a good faith effort at this yourself. Make sure you have references to your text controls (e.g., `IBOutlet` if you created them in IB). Then you can write code for your button (e.g. an `IBAction`). And your code can refer to the `text` properties of those text controls.

Comment: Maybe good idea is create this as table view and put my text to row no. 1 computer no.2 and my updated text to row no.1 and after send empty strung i will switch on row no 3 ?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with something super simple: Basic scene with just the three controls, the button, the text field, and the text view (or whatever you want). Why complicate it yet with the table view? Once you've mastered the simple layout, then you can move on to something fancier.

Comment: I have like U said. And when i add text with `textView.text = textView.text + "text /n New Line"`  auto scroll bottom doesn't work. If i added text like `textView.text = textView.text + "text"` is ok :(